# Is it possible to optimistically update all caches of a endpoint?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In the redux tutorial, we learned how to perform optimistic updates:

[part-8-rtk-query-advanced#implementing-optimistic-updates](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#implementing-optimistic-updates)

But in the API reference of [updateQueryData](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/cache-management-utils#updatequerydata), I found that an `args` must be passed in:

```js
const updateQueryData = (
  endpointName: string,
  args: any,
  updateRecipe: (draft: Draft<CachedState>) => void
) => ThunkAction<PatchCollection, PartialState, any, AnyAction>;
```

So, if our post has pagination,

```js
getPosts: builder.query({
  query: (current: number) => `/posts?current=${current}`,
  providesTags: ['Post']
}),
```

At this time, how will we perform an optimistic update?

```js
// Is there a way to update all getPosts caches?
// Am I missing some documents?
apiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getPosts', ???, (draft) => {
  const post = draft.find((post) => post.id === postId)
  if (post) {
    post.reactions[reaction]++
  }
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Redux Toolkit 1.7, that is possible.

It contains a `api.util.selectInvalidatedBy` helper function that allows you to get all endpoints with arguments that `provide`d a specific tag.

It can be used as following:

```js
   async onQueryStarted({ id, ...patch }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled, getState }) {
     for (const { endpointName, originalArgs } of api.util.selectInvalidatedBy(getState(), [{ type: "Post", id}])) { 
       // we only want to update `getPosts` here
       if ( endpointName !== 'getPosts') continue;
       dispatch(
         api.util.updateQueryData(endpoint, originalArgs, (draft) => {
            // find in list & update
         })
       )
     }, 
   },
```

Comment: There's a typo here, the function is not directly available in api. You need to use api.util.selectInvalidatedBy

Comment: Also, in the type, I had to use an array, even if it's only 1 type.

Comment: Good point, I'll correct it. I just wrote it mainly by memory.

Answer (score 0):

A bit refactored version(without heavyweight for loop)

```
addPost: builder.mutation({
  query: (body) => ({
    url: '/posts',
    method: 'POST',
    body,
  }),
  async onQueryStarted(args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled, getState }) {
    try {
      const { data: createdPost } = await queryFulfilled;

      const postsCache = api.util.selectInvalidatedBy(getState(), [
        { type: 'Posts' },
      ]);

      postsCache
        .filter(({ endpointName }) => endpointName === 'getPosts')
        .forEach(({ originalArgs }) => {
          dispatch(
            api.util.updateQueryData(
              'getPosts',
              originalArgs,
              (draft) => {
                draft?.push(createdPost);
              },
            ),
          );
        });
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
    }
  },
}),
```